# How to make a dialog window always on the front at my application level

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog, always-on-top

How can I make a Qt dialog window always on top at my application level?

I want to make a dialog window always on the front but remember always on the front at my application level, even if I click on an empty place, I want to it stay on the front of my application only.

I have tried to use `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)`, but this makes the dialog window always on the top at the desktop level, but I want it to be on top at the my application level only.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Try to set Qt::Dialog or Qt::Window flag to your dialog (with setWindowsFlags method)

Comment: @Chernobyl: I have used `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool)` with the dialog window.

Comment: Then you should setParent to this window. From doc:Indicates that the widget is a tool window. A tool window is often a small window with a smaller than usual title bar and decoration, typically used for collections of tool buttons. If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it. If there isn't a parent, you may consider using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint as well.

Comment: @Chernobyl: your words correct, set the parent is the problem (`+1` for your comment). thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the dialogs a parent. A child dialog always stays on top of its parent window.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't send `parent` to your dialog_window (based on code conditional) Like me, use flags.

```
Dialog_dlg::Dialog_dlg(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog_dlg)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setFixedSize(width(), height()); //for no maximaize
    setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
}
```

I used this and good to me. See other flags, test them, and choose.